# How to transform SELECT list of columns into JOIN rules

Tags: notepad++

In SQL Server I use to pass between SELECT clause and JOIN clause. In other words I have the following list of columns:

```
[FirstColumn],
[SecondColumn],
[ThirdColumn],
```

And I need to have the following

```
A.[FirstColumn]=B.[FirstColumn]
A.[SecondColumn]=B.[SecondColumn]
A.[ThirdColumn]=B.[ThirdColumn]
```

Is there a way to automate this transformation in Notepad++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Replace (Search -> Replace, or Ctrl+H), with Search Mode = Regular expression:

Find what: `^(\[.*?\]),? *$`

Replace with: `A.\1=B.\1`

Check In selection (optional)

[image]

---

to automate:

- Macros -> Start Recording
- find/replace operation
- Macros -> Stop Recording
- Macros -> Save a Current Recorded Macro (Name & optional shortcut combo)

---

regex search explanation:

```
^           line start
(           start capture group
\[          line starts with [
.*?         grab all the characters until
\]          ]
)           end capture group
,? *        ignore possible trailing comma and trailing spaces
$           line end
```

replace explanation:

```
A.\1=B.\1     A.(CapturedGroup1)=B.(CapturedGRoup1)
```

Comment: `^` matches start of line, the parenthesis `(` create a match group to grab the "[something]".  A match group allows you to referenced that substring twice in the replacement as `\1`